# Twitter Bootstrap Remove Margin of the Span

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap. And i have used span8 and span 4 in a row. Is there anyway to remove the leading margin-left:20px from the first span of the row without needing to over ride it manually ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That 20px margin you see on your `#mainContent` area is due to the setup of the bootstrap grid, which uses a container of `940px`, it is supposed to be removed by the `.row` container with a `margin-left:-20px` property. In your setup, your content area is working just the way it was designed too, but your top `pageHeader` and `mainNav` sections are not appropriately inserted into the grid, you just have divs inside the `.row` top sections that are not being contained within the proper containers of the grid.

To fix this you can just insert all of your `pageHeader` and `mainNav` elements inside a `.span12` container and everything should stack accordingly.

**Fixed markup**

```
<header class="row" id="pageHeader">
    <div class="span12">
        <div id="logo">Logo</div>
        <div id="userDetails">userDetails</div>
    </div>
</header>

<nav id="mainNav" class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="dashboard.html">Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="idea_exchange.html">Idea Exchange</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Also, quick tip, you can switch your `mainNav` background color to the proper grid container of `.span12` simply by targeting it like so:

```
nav#mainNav .span12 {
    background: url("../images/nav_bar_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

you can add a class in your css with an !important:

example:

```
.no_margin{
margin:0px !important;
}
```

and add that class to your html when required.

(sorry for my bad english xD)

Answer (score 2):

there is also small less utility at

http://getkickstrap.com/extras/#single-view

called flushspan

Comment: The link is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

By using "row" or "row-fluid" class as parent of your span class

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="dashboard.html">Dashboard</a></li>
           <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
           <li><a href="idea_exchange.html">Idea Exchange</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```